# Comparing basicity using inductive effect

Tags: acid-base

In the following two compounds .

1)[image]

2)[image]

We have to compare basicity .

According to me CH$_3$ is an electron donating compound so in second compound it will increase charge density in nitrogen so second compound should be more basic.

But in the book it is written first is more basic . How

Comment: @KlausWarzecha but in that question the compounds are different

Comment: Yes, the specific compounds are different. The basis for making a decision  is not.